# Why don't we use $F=−kx$ while finding a spring constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, displacement

[image: HRK-V-1-Sample-Problem-11-4 , pg 237]A block of mass $m$ is attached to a vertical spring in equilibrium, and is stretched a distance $d$.

As Hook's law is $F=-kd$

If I take $y$-axis to be positive upward, the net force in the $y$ direction at equilibrium should be $\sum F_y=-kd-mg=0$, but it is $\sum F_y=kd-mg=0$.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to choose a well defined sign convention then follow it rigorously when doing problems like this, and you are to be congratulated for doing so. But you have tripped yourself up by not following your sign convention rigorously. Remember that since the $y$ axis is positive in the upwards direction then when you add the mass to the spring the displacement is a negative number, because it is a displacement in the downwards direction. So if we call the displacement $d$ then $d \lt 0$.

Once you remember this you'll find your original equation:

$$ F_y=-kd-mg=0 $$

works correctly. In the first term the displacement $d$ is a negative number so since $k$ is positive we find $-kd$ is a positive number i.e. it is an upwards force exactly as it should be.

What I suspect you have done is to take the displacement as $-d$, so the displacement is overall negative but the number $d$ is positive. In that case your equation becomes:

$$ F_y=-k(-d)-mg=0 $$

which of course simplifies to:

$$ F_y=+kd-mg=0 $$

Comment: the writer should properly write it as $k=\frac{-mg}{-0.124m}$ in the pic.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, there is nothing incorrect about the formula

-kd - mg = 0.

Since you have defined down to be the negative convention, than when the spring stretches to its equilibrium state, d will be a negative value, and so the overall force from the spring will be positive (ie - directed up.) It's just a bit confusing because you intrinsically defined g to be positive by giving the force due to gravity an overall minus sign, when really your equation should read:

-kd + mg = 0

where g = -9.81 m/s^2

It's important to realize that when applying Newton's second law, you are dealing with vector quantities. The Net force is the SUM of the forces, and gravity is not a restorative force so there should be no negative sign naturally associated with it. The negative sign only comes from the fact that you have chosen down to be negative, whereas the spring force will ALWAYS show up as negative in the formula since it is restorative.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a matter of convention. Are positive forces tensile or compressive? Is positive displacement an extension or a retraction?

Those two conventions force us to use $F = k \delta$ or $F = -k \delta$.

That is why you always need a free body diagram, and consistent conventions in order to get the correct signs in the balance equations.

Answer (score 0):

On what body are these forces acting?

If they are acting *on the block* then the force on the block due to the tension in the spring (acting upwards) is $+kd$, and the force on it due to gravity (acting downwards) is $-mg$.

When we write $F=-kx$ for the spring the minus sign indicates that the tension force $F$ is in the opposite direction to the direction of increasing extension $x$. In your case $d$ is being measured in the direction of *decreasing* extension.